# How do I add an image with a link to my home page in Umbraco?

Tags: image, url, umbraco

I'm new to Umbraco and I need to know how to insert an image with a link/url?

For example -->

```
<a href="http://somesite.com"><img src="/map/image.png"/></a>
```

UPDATE:
Below is a screenshot which doesn't show any button to insert an image.

[image]

Comment: Can you extend more the question? Do you have a Document Type already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the editor? Just insert the image, then select it and click the link button.

In Umbraco 7, using the grid, you have to go to Developer section and locate the datatype(s) used for the grid property you are using. There should be an option to customize the rich text editor buttons somewhere in there.

Comment: I'm in the editor right now, in Content -> Home and I can't insert an image and click the link button.

Comment: What Umbraco version is it? In Umbraco 7 using the grid it's a bit different, but if there is a rich text editor property it should be simple enough. Could you be just a little bit more informative? Screenshots maybe?

Comment: Thank you very much Jannik! This made my day ;-)

Comment: As default the Image-property in the Grid editor dosn't contain a link option for the image.  Use this blog, to create a Custom Editor to solve your problem.:  https://our.umbraco.com/forum/umbraco-7/using-umbraco-7/64201-The-Spirit-of-Sharing-Images-With-Links-in-a-Grid